# How to submit a form or press the enter key on an input with react-native-testing-library

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, react-testing-library, react-native-testing-library

I have the following problem: I need to test if a function is being called on my test, but to test it properly I need to press enter or submit the form, and it doesn't seem to work as intended. I've already tried the following:

```js
fireEvent.keyDown(input, { key: 'Enter', code: 'Enter' });
fireEvent.submit(input);
```

The only way to trigger the `onSubmitEditing` prop of my component is by pressing the Enter key.

Here's the code I'm trying to test:

```js
<Input placeholder="Cirurgião"
    testID='input_buscaCirurgiao_index'
    value={this.state.text}
    autoCorrect={false}
    keyboardType={(Platform.OS === 'android') ? 'visible-password' : 'default'}
    onChangeText={(item) => this.setState({ text: item })}
    onSubmitEditing={() => { this._searchPressingEnter() }} // i need to test this
    autoCapitalize='none' 
/>
```

Here's the code for the `_searchPressingEnter` function:

```js
_searchPressingEnter() {
    Keyboard.dismiss()

    let item = this.state.text

    this._buscarCirurgioes(item)
}
```

Once the Enter key has been pressed, the `_searchPressingEnter` function should be called, thus triggering the `onSubmitEditing` prop.

Comment: are you using Jest? - this might help https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro/

Comment: Yeah, I could simply spy on the function and verify if it is being called, but for it to be called, I need to submit the form by pressing enter. Clicking on the input won't trigger onSubmitEditing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your test case you can fire the `submitEditing` event.

```js
// Assuming `input` is your text input element
fireEvent(input, 'submitEditing')
```

For more details on triggering events check: https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/api#fireevent.

Comment: This actually worked for me!!! Thanks very much. Tried several different things and none of them worked, until now.

Comment: Not sure why, but in my example, I have got `no handler function found for event: "submitEditing"`.
My `@testing-library/react-native` is ver `"^7.2.0"`.
Also I'm not sure why it is called `input` not `TextInput` element. And I couldn't find `submitEdditing` in https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput or in the link you have sent above. Could you give the source, how you have found solution?

Comment: The name of the handler is [onSubmitEditing](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onsubmitediting), `fireEvent(input, 'submitEditing')` will trigger that event on the `TextInput` element. The source is the link I provide in the answer - you can fire _any_ event present in the `fireEvent` API.